# Open Javascript onclick URL with chrome extension's linkUrl

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developing simple web view chrome extension with iframe.

If my cursor is right click anchor link than I want to make open that link on a new tab. I made this feature with following code.

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({  
     title: "Open link in new tab",  
     contexts: ["link"],  
     onclick: function search(OnClickData) {  
       chrome.tabs.create ({url: OnClickData.linkUrl}) }
  });
```

The problem is if link is set with `onclick` method like this,

```
<div class="demo" onclick="location.href='?bo_table=cm_iphonien&amp;bo_style=view&amp;wr_id=1844771&amp;page='">
```

My code can't render this link as a link. So how can I open Javascript `onclick` URL with chrome extension's `linkUrl`??

Answer (score 0):

The following should render as a link:

```
<a href="#" class="demo" onclick="location.href='?bo_table=cm_iphonien&bo_style=view&wr_id=1844771&page='">
```